# How to replace 0.00 values with null in OBIEE12c . my column datatype is number

Tags: obiee

How to replace 0.00 values with null in OBIEE12c . my column datatype is number
i need to apply it in RPD or as a self servicing report . it is not require for dashboard and prebuild report

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement in the column formula of the report, e.g.

```sql
case "MyTable"."MyColumn" when 0 then null else "MyTable"."MyColumn" end
```

Comment: "MyTable"."MyColumn" is number data type . Null can not be use in number datatype

Answer (score 0):

0 and NULL are totally different things in analytics and what you're trying to do is already conceptually wrong.

If you made 500 this month and -500 last month does NOT mean you did NULL when aggregating both months. You did 0. And that also why you can't use NULL with numerical data types because you can not aggregate NULL.

Please don't force the system to violate all rules of data processing just do pull some GUI stunts.

EDIT: "Show blank"? Well you're supposed to be doing analytics with corporate data and not MS Paint, but here goes: Set a conditional rule on the column where value = 0 and then set a custom CSS style of "display:none". Ridiculous but will do what you want.

Comment: Insted of null can i show blank ? Pls advise

Comment: Reply and answer in the updated response above

Comment: In Self serving reporting we can not save Condition rule filter .. only for report or Dashbaord we can able to do

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to save as a system wide default for that column.
Set the formatting you want and then on column properties click the save as default and save as the system wide default for that column

Both options will work in the front end but the value will still be output if you export data

## Conditional Formatting

Create an analysis with the column you want formatting in.
Add conditional formatting where this value = 0
Either set the font size to 0 or use an image and set to image only

## Custom Number Format

Set the number format to be #